# Datatables.net: How to set a document's title (excelHtml5 and pdfHtml5) based on an input field?

Tags: jquery, datatables, datatables-1.10

I'm using Datatables.net and I need to change the title of an exported document (excelHtml5 and pdfHtml5) based on the value of an input field.
The idea is for the user to change the exported files title based on their searches.

For now all my buttons have the same title value:

```
{
    extend: 'excelHtml5',
    title: 'Title 1', //change this value based on an input field
},
{
    extend: 'pdfHtml5',
    title: 'Title 2', //change this value based on an input field
}
```

How can i accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

To update the title property of a export button, i used the action method of that button:

```
action: function (e, dt, node, config)
{
    ///update title property based on the added input field
    config.title = $("#exportTitle").val();

    ///procede with the export
    $.fn.dataTable.ext.buttons.excelHtml5.action(e, dt, node, config);
},
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I found this to work in my case. 
[jQuery DataTable Set Title On Button Click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46568585/jquery-datatable-set-title-on-button-click/46569819#46569819?newreg=7c1c63789702483f8e02c6304e469dec)

```
buttons: [
            {
                extend: 'excelHtml5',
                title: function() {
                    return $("#exportTitle").val();
                }
            },
            {
                extend: 'pdfHtml5',
                title: function() {
                    return $("#exportTitle").val();
                }
            }
        ]
```

Answer (score 0):

use **text** as title in your datatables buttons

```
buttons:[
    {
        extend: 'excelHtml5',
        text:'Export Excel',
    },
],
```