# jQuery DataTable Set Title On Button Click

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

On my view, I have 2 input fields, 1 button and 1 table of which I am using [jQuery DataTables](https://datatables.net/).

I am using the [print functionality](https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/print/simple.html) on my datatable.

I am trying to set the title of the print page based off of the values of the 2 input fields, but it is not working.

On page load, the 2 input fields will be blank.. which is where the button comes into play.  If that button is clicked then both of those fields will have a value and I need those values to be incorporated into the title.

Here is my jQuery:

```
var startDate = "";
var endDate = "";

$("#Search-Btn").click(function() {
    startDate = $("#Start-Date").val();
    endDate = $("#End-Date").val();
});

var firstTable = $("#Month-Table").DataTable({
    dom: 'Bfrtip',
    buttons: [
    {
        extend: 'print',
        title: 'Title For ' + locationName + ' ' + startDate + ' - ' + endDate,
        exportOptions: {
            columns: ':not(:last-child)'
        }
    }],
    "searching": false,
    "paging": false
});
```

**Problem:**

Because the datatable is setup on page load.. I can't set the title to incorporate the `startDate` and `endDate` based on button click.  I can't set properties of the datatable based on other events.

Is there a way to do this?

**HTML**

```
<div class="col-md-4 date-range">
    <div class="input-group date datetimepicker">
        @Html.TextBox("startDate", null, new { id = "Start-Date", @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Start Date" })
        <span class="input-group-addon">
            <span class="fa fa-calendar"></span>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-1 date-range">
    <p class="text-center">
        <span class="fa fa-minus"></span>
    </p>
</div>

<div class="col-md-4 date-range">
    <div class="input-group date datetimepicker">
        @Html.TextBox("endDate", null, new { id = "End-Date", @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "End Date" })
        <span class="input-group-addon">
            <span class="fa fa-calendar"></span>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I added the `startDate` and `endDate` HTML.. no need to upload the table.. that is a basic html table.

Comment: So what I am reading in the [documentation](https://datatables.net/reference/api/buttons.exportInfo()) is that the `title` option is a `buttons.exportInfo()` type. So you can make it into a function and return a value from within it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment, the `title` option is of type [`buttons.exportInfo()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/buttons.exportInfo()). You can evaluate anything into the title, and return a string:

```
...
buttons: [
            {
              extend: 'print',
              title: function() {
                  return 'Title For Location here ' + $("#Start-Date").val() + ' - ' + $("#End-Date").val();
              }
            }
        ]
...
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hescano/4tuupc5f/32/)

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  This works.  I have another question but it is directly related to this one.  I thought if I had this part then the other part would be easy, but apparently not.. I really have 3 inputs on my form.. 2 of them are what you see above... the other is `#Single-Date-TxtBox`.  Basically, if `#Single-Date-TxtBox` has a value then use that date in the title.. if not then use the dates in `#Start-Date` and `#End-Date`.  Any idea on how to do this?

Comment: Nvmd figured it out.  Thanks.

Comment: @GTown-Coder sorry I was eating lunch. I am glad you figured it out.